# Prisma doesn't generate files when running prisma init

Tags: docker, docker-compose, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

Running prisma init does not generate files. It not generates the 3 files below.

1. datamodel.graphql
2. docker-compose.yml
3. prisma.yml

end up getting this error:-

```
{
     "errors": [
     {
        "message": "Project not found: 'graphiql@default'",
        "code": 3016,
        "requestId": "local:api:cjh3r908l000s0834adw100sj"
     }
  ] 
}
```

Comment: Prisma 1 is an older version. As you're getting started, go for Prisma 2 https://www.prisma.io/docs/getting-started/quickstart-node

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have also encountered this problem, and what worked for me was changing the **Node version** in my local.

When I used `Node v14.x.x.`, when running `$ prisma init <project_name>`, no prisma files were generated

But when I changed my Node version to use `v12.x.x` or specifically `v.12.19.1`, everything went well as expected.

Thus, it's better when using **Prisma 1**, use `Node v12.19.1` or any versions below `v14.x.x`.

---

If you're using `nvm`, just run these commands:

```
$ nvm install 12.19.1
$ nvm use 12.19.1
$ node -v                   // Check and confirm your node version

$ prisma init <project_name>
```